# Can't synchronize my threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I've a problem when I try to sychronize my threads. I have the next code:

```
static void* CarProcess(void *str);

int main()
{
    thread_t *pthreadsArray;
    pthreadsArray = (thread_t*)malloc(sizeof(thread_t) * 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int pthread = mythread_create(&pthreadsArray[i], NULL, CarProcess, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mythread_join(pthreadsArray[i], NULL);
    }
}

static void* CarProcess(void *str)
{
    while(1){
        printf("Thread ID: %i\n", str);
    }   
}
```

When I execute the program, I have this output:

```
Thread ID: 0
Thread ID: 0
Thread ID: 0
Thread ID: 0
...
```

But never appears "Thread ID: 1", "Thread ID: 2", "Thread ID: 3"....or "Thread ID: 9". I think that it could be solved using Mutex, locking and unloking Mutex.. Does any body have idea how to solve that? Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I assume your actual program have a dynamic number of threads? Otherwise using `malloc` is just unnecessary and you could just use a normal array.

Comment: Also, what is `mythread_create` and `mythread_join`?

Comment: thank you @JoachimPileborg, but it seems that you don't know a lot about threads.. Create and Join are functions from the thread library..

Comment: I know about `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`. I don't know anything about `mythread_create` and `mythread_join`.

Comment: `void*` is not `int`, why do you think you can interchange between the two freely? If you want to convert one to the other, use an explicit cast.

Comment: "the" thread library? Does it have a web page?

Comment: I've implemented my own POSIX thread library

Comment: Then are you sure your own thread library works? If you switch to using the *standard* POSIX thread functions, does it work as expected?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure that it works..

Comment: POSIX Standar says: "The join function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has already terminated".. That's why it only executes the first THREAD.. I think that using Mutex could solve the problem, but don't know how exactly use it and I don't find something good searching in Google

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Unless your thread library can be comfortably copied and pasted as a part of your example, you cannot rely on it.

Comment: I have tried your code, but with the POSIX standard thread functions and with casting and other minor fixes because of warnings from the compiler, and it works fine. The problem is either because of the casting issue, or in the thread code you don't show.

Answer (score 2):

One possible source of the problem is that `str` is not really an `int` variable. You need to do some casting (both when creating the thread and when getting the argument).

To create a the thread and to properly pass the integer to ity ou first need to cast the value to an `intptr_t`, which is a [standard integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) big enough to fit both an integer or a pointer. Then you should cast it to a generic pointer (i.e. `void *`):

```
pthread_create(&pthreadsArray[i], NULL, CarProcess, (void *) (intptr_t) i);
```

Then to get the integer value inside the thread function you need to do the opposite casting:

```
static void* CarProcess(void *str)
{
    int i = (int) (intptr_t) str;
    printf("Thread ID: %i\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not in the variable casting.. Is synchronizing the threads.. I need multithreading..

Comment: @ArturoSalas If the code is exactly what you show, then there's no need for any synchronization. None of the threads access any shared data. Synchronization is only needed if you access shared data in a way that one thread may modify it while another reads it.

Comment: It's only printing the message from the first Thread and not the other 9 threads.. this is not multithreaded